# Having trouble with a USB drive data corruption

Tags: mount, data-recovery, usb-drive, data-corruption

I was given a new 15 TB USB drive and was going to use it to store a lot of my files. I formatted it NTFS so I can take it between my Ubuntu (desktop) and Win 11 (laptop) machines as I have a lot of things that I wanted to do on both. Somewhere in the process of moving files from my Ubuntu machine's hard drive to the new drive something has gone horribly wrong and it corrupted the drive and so I started the process of trying to do data recovery using Wondershare Recoverit on the Win 11 machine. Being a huge drive it was taking a long time and at 90% done my beloved spouse closed my laptop and it shut down the app. Now Windows can tell there's a drive there but won't let me see anything on it and Ubuntu is the same way in Disks and in the Terminal. Windows won't give me errors but Ubuntu at least gave me the following error when I tired to mount it and I'm hoping someone can guide me through fixing the drive and recovering the data!

Using:

```
Disk /dev/sde: 15.26 TiB, 16777216000000 bytes, 4096000000 sectors

Disk model: UDisk        
   
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x73736572


|Device  |   Boot |    Start     |   End |   Sectors | Size |Id| Type|

|/dev/sde1   |    1920221984 |3736432267| 1816210284|  6.8T |72 |unknown|

|/dev/sde2    |   1936028192| 3889681299 |1953653108|  7.3T| 6c| unknown|

|/dev/sde3     |           0   |       0   |       0 |   0B|  0 |Empty|

|/dev/sde4    |     27722122  | 27722568     |   447 | 1.7M|  0|Empty|




$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sde /mnt

Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x58444e49  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 4  data: 2098  usn: 50: Input/output error

Corrupt index block signature: vcn 3 inode 5

Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory

Failed to mount '/dev/sde': No such file or directory
```

Of interest to me:

- What does the error "Incomplete multi-sector transfer" mean?
- Can the "corrupt index block signature" be repaired?
- What tools would I need to use?
- Can I, a n00bie to drive repair do this myself?
- Where do I start, step by step please?

Any ideas help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Sue

Comment: Not sure you if can recover much. Was it gpt before? "Disklabel type: dos" Any drive over 2TiB must be gpt partitioned. DOS has a 2TB max. There were some early proprietary work arounds. Or you converted your 15TB drive to 2TB. You need to know for sure if gpt or DOS to run recovery software. Typically NTFS recovery works better with Windows tools. And most tools need a drive of same size as data to recovery or another 15GB drive. You may want that anyway. Orginal issue may be Windows fast start up/hibernation which resets data to as hibernated, so any write from Linux disappears.

Comment: Is there a way I can get Windows to recognize the drive again? How do I tell if it was gpt before? It was a new drive when I started. Win 11 showed that it was 15TB so I thought everything was fine. Do I just need to hand this over to a specialist?

Comment: Almost all partitioning tools of recent vintage would create gpt, not MBR. So how did drive become MBR? Some older Windows tools convert gpt to MBR, but leave backup gpt table that is at end of drive. Does this show a backup gpt table? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sde` Confirm that drive is still shown as sde or change to correct drive.